# How can I make different columns render as different colors in holoviews / hvplot?

Tags: pandas, holoviews

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns of time series data. In my actual data, these columns are large enough that the render is unwieldy without datashader. I am attempting to compare events from these two timeseries. However, I need to be able to tell which data point is from which column. A simple functional example is below. How would I get columns A and B to use different color maps?

```
import numpy as np
import hvplot.pandas
import pandas as pd

A = np.random.randint(10, size=10000)
B = np.random.randint(30, size=10000)
d = {'A':A,'B':B}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.hvplot(kind='scatter',datashade=True, height=500, width=1000, dynspread=False)
```

Comment: Seems like you could separately datashade each curve with its own colormap, then overlay the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the count_cat aggregator that counts each category separately, e.g. in the example above that would look like this:

```
import datashader as ds
df.hvplot(kind='scatter', aggregator=ds.count_cat('Variable'), datashade=True,
          height=500, width=1000)
```

The `'Variable'` here corresponds to the default `group_label` that hvplot assigns to the columns. If you provided a different `group_label` you would have to update the aggregator to match. However instead of supplying an aggregator explicitly you can also use the `by` keyword:

```
df.hvplot(kind='scatter', by='Variable', datashade=True,
          height=500, width=1000)
```

Once hvplot 0.3.1 is released you'll also be able to supply an explicit `cmap`, e.g.:

```
df.hvplot(kind='scatter', by='Variable', datashade=True,
          height=500, width=1000, cmap={'A': 'red', 'B': 'blue'})
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great - thanks. I have a follow on question, sorry if this expands the scope a little bit. Since the solution doesn't allow for manually assigning colors, on my working dataset, I can't tell which set is the blue, and which set is the red. I tried adding a "legend=True" parameter inside the df.hvplot command, but no legend appears. Do you know of a way to either manually specify the colors for columns, or get a legend to show up?

Comment: Automatic legends for datashaded plots are high on our to do list. In holoviews it is also possible to pass a dictionary as the `cmap` but that is not currently supported in hvplot. I'll add support for that in the coming days and push a minor release out, but you'd manually have to add a legend by overlaying some dummy points, e.g. ``hv.Points([(0, 0, 'Variable1'), (0, 0, 'Variable2'), ...], vdims='Variable').opts(color='Variable', cmap={'Variable1': 'red', ...})``.

Comment: I've now amended the answer for a simplified signature and to note the support for an explicit cmap which will be added in hvplot 0.3.1 due to be released today.